# Learning light transport using Q-Learning

Tags: raytracing, pathtracing, importance-sampling

I am trying to reproduce the results obtained by Dahm et al. in the paper [Learning Light Transport the Reinforced Way](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07403v1.pdf?utm_content=buffer5b1d2&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer). 
This method takes advantage of the similarity between the Bellman equation (Q-Learning) and the rendering equation. 
Here's the overview of the code authors inserted in the first version of their paper:

[image]

**Question 1**

What is, in the first function, `idxPrev`? Intuition suggests it is the index of the previous cell. 
EDIT: `ray.o` is probably the origin. 
Moreover, in the same function, I understand that `getLastAttenuation()` returns the color of `idxCurr`. How is getLastAttenuation calculated?

**Question 2**

The action space is discretized, apparently, dividing the hemisphere built on the hitting point in different stratums. According to what I understand, the Q-Learning algorithm finds the best action (so the best stratum) for each cell in the space, and then a ray is scattered randomly in that stratum. But a stratum covers 360 degrees, so I don't see how this is helpful to scattered a ray towards the light. 
In the function `sampleScatteringDIrFromQtable()`, the PDF is calculated based on the `ps` (not clear) multiplied by the number of patches. So, the action is related to circular stratums of the hemisphere, or the number of patches?

**UPDATE:** 
**Question 3**

I divide the hemispheres over the hitting points in 24 equally-sized patches. Then I scatter rays, for now, not based on a uniform distribution on the hemisphere, but through the center of these 24 equally-sized patched. In this case, what would the PDF be?

Comment: `ray.o` almost always denote the origin, for what it's worth.